# Menu style application, such as google.com Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

you've seen GOOGLE.COM Android smartphone with Chrome?

Have you noticed the MENU 'pop-up similar to an application. This menu has a "SPRING", I would like to understand how google got this result.

I used the property "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" but I do not get this result.

is very interesting to note, too, that came in the bottom of the menu, continue scrolling, the page does not move, which now leads normalente, finished scrolling of a DIV FIXED it starts to scroll the page below (something annoying)

Can you tell me what it used google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) it create the same view as Google sliding menu